# No overload of WriteLine matches delegate with same signature

Tags: c#, delegates

I was recently writing some code to do WriteLine using a delegate in .NET 3.5.
It was all going well using various different Action delegates until I came to the overload of WriteLine which is

`public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3)`

As I'm using .NET 3.5 there is no `Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>` delegate so I quicly wrote my own:

`public delegate void Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5);`

I then went to assign WriteLine to this method `Action<string, object, object, object, object> action = Console.WriteLine;` and I got the error message

> No overload for 'WriteLine' matches delegate 'Action<string,object,object,object,object>'

I thought this must be caused as a result of some generics issue so I explicitly declared a new delegate:

`public delegate void WriteLineAction(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3);`

I then tried assigning WriteLine to this new method and again got the error message:

> No overload for 'WriteLine' matches delegate 'WriteLineAction'

The even stranger thing is that if I right click on the Console.WriteLine call that's in error and say "Go To Definition" it takes me to the **right version of WriteLine** in the metadata, so why is it not able to match the method to the delegate. Am I doing something really stupid here or is this a known issue / feature?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're implementing flexible logging, then you might want to look into a library like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).  It rocks :)

Comment: You are right, this is weird... I just copied the signatures of the WriteLine methods into a new static class and when I point the delegate to those, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [docs for this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc0cx9a5.aspx#Y0) it shows:

> This API is not CLS-compliant. The CLS-compliant alternative is `WriteLine(String, Object[])`.

and if you look at the C# tab in the signature, it says:

> C# does not support methods that use variable length arguments (varargs).
>   The compiler automatically resolves calls to this method to the same method that uses a parameter array.

The C++ tab shows the signature as:

```
public:
static void WriteLine(
    String^ format, 
    Object^ arg0, 
    Object^ arg1, 
    Object^ arg2, 
    Object^ arg3, 
    ...
)
```

I strongly suspect this is the issue. In Reflector it shows up as:

```
public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0, object arg1,
    object arg2, object arg3, __arglist)
```

Comment: Ah right, I was using the VS9.0 version of the documentation which doesn't mention it being resolved to the other method like the .NET 4 one does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc0cx9a5(v=VS.90).aspx